# ROS Answers SE migration: ros2 turtlesim

Tags: ros, ros2, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am using ros2 dashing and work with turtlesim (1.0.1). Unfortunatly, I realized that a number of features described in the tutorial do not work for me.

1. Action Servers explained in [Understanding ROS Actions](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Understanding-ROS2-Actions/) are not available. According to the tutorial I expected to see something like `Action Servers: /turtle1/rotate_absolute: turtlesim/action/RotateAbsolute`. But when I run

   > ros2 node info /turtlesim

no actions are visible.

```
    /turtlesim
    Subscribers:
        ...
    Publishers:
        ...
     Services:
        ...
```

2. The Parameter setting is described in [Understanding ROS2 Parameters](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Parameters/Understanding-ROS2-Parameters/). When I run

   ```
   > ros2 param set /turtlesim background_r 150
   ```

I receive

```
    Set parameter successful
```

but nothing happens, the background remains in the same color as before. I assume that I am doing something wrong. Does someone have advice for me?

Best wishes!

Sebastian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339944/ros2-turtlesim/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2019-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The overview page for the [beginner tutorials](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/) states:

> Currently, the beginner level tutorials target **Eloquent**. Certain features may not be available for older distributions.

The `ros2 node info` command listing actions is one of those. It is only available as of Eloquent.

Regarding the immediate update of the background color when setting the parameter: that feature is available in `turtlesim` in Dashing. You just need to use the latest version which is 1.0.2 in Dashing.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on 2019-12-14**:
Many thanks for the fast answer!